# как сделать импорт большой базы данных в phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, terminal

Как импортировать большую базу данных в PHPMyAdmin,у меня она около 800Мб, как это сделать с помощью Terminal в Mac OS?

Comment: Так вам в PhpMyAdmin или в терминале нужно? Может тогда заголовок изменить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Импорт большой базы данных с помощью консоли (терминала):

1) Необходимо загрузить файл с дампом базы на VPS. Для этого можно использовать подключение по SFTP-протоколу с правами root.

Установив SFTP соединение, копируем sql-файл в любую директорию на сервере, например, /root.

2) Теперь подключаемся к VPS через SSH-консоль с правами root. Такой уровень доступа вы получаете по умолчанию, заказав любой хостинг виртуальных серверов.

Подключаемся к серверу MySQL командой:

mysql -u root(Имя пользователя с помощью которого вы входите в phpmyadmin) –p

Например, mysql -u oleg –p

Вводим пароль mysql-пользователя root и нажимаем Enter. В результате в консоли будет выведено приветствие «Welcome to the MySQL monitor.» с указанием id сессии и версии MySQL.

3) Зайдем в созданную базу данных при помощи команды:

USE database_name (имя базы данных)

Например, USE nano (имя базы данных)

4) Для импорта дампа БД используется команда source. В случае с файлом database.sql команда будет следующей:

source /root/database.sql;

Визуальный пример выполнения этой команды представлен ниже:

mysql> source /root/database.sql; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec) 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec) 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) 
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec) 
Database changed 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec) 
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec) 
Records: 4 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) 
mysql>

[image: Фотографи №1]

[image: Фотографи №2]

Answer (score 3):

Консольная команда для импорта базы из sql файла

```
mysql -u[username] -p[password] db_name < dump.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Попробуйте вместо PhpMyAdmin сделать дамп в [Sypex Dumper](https://sypex.net/), а на целевом сервере с его помощью залить. Он гигабайтами таскать способен информацию.
2. Идущая в комплекте к серверу утилита mysql. [Старая дока](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/mysqldump.html)
   Возможно придётся в параметрах к mysql дополнительно [указывать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-mysql-dump-file) хост, логин, пароль

Answer (score 2):

В терминале открываете файл php.ini -> `sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

В котором меняете значения на:

> ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
>
> upload_max_filesize = 200M
>
> ; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
>
> post_max_size = 200M
>
> ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
>
> max_execution_time = 600
>
> ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
>
> max_input_time = 600
>
> ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
>
> memory_limit = 500M

После перезапускаем сервер -> `sudo service apache2 reload`
. Производим импорт. На выходе получаем 200Мб, по необходимости можете менять значения.

Answer (score -1):

измените 128 МБ im php.ini теперь работает для моего wamp, я использую программное обеспечение MYSQL Banchmark для импорта, и это было нормально для базы данных 190 МБ

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык